# Do I need to Create a Mobile App for retrieve data from Google Fitness API

Tags: php, rest, android-wear-data-api, google-fit

I just need to create a web application to analyse the daily fitness records.

I plan to monitor daily activities from Google Fitness API
I installed [Google Fit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.fitness&hl=en) application from Google Playstore
It successfully track my daily activities

Now I needs to retrieve those data to my web application

**Is It possible to retrieve data from 3rd party application?**
I heard this app is sync data to my account in cloud
Therefore I can able to retrieve data, isn't it?

My Question is-
Do I need to create a separate app for my work or can I retrieve data from google cloud

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need to create a separate Android app.  There are perfectly usable [Rest API's](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/)